# Azure function failing to run with error Could not load type Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have deployed an azure function and it was working fine since last week but it suddenly failed running with error "**Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'** ". When I looked at the azure portal I have identified that the last version has updated to a different version. Do I need to update Nuget packages and redeploy it again?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the version upgrade of Azure SDK by Microsoft

To **temporarily** avoid impact, you can pin your Function App to the previous version of the runtime by updating the app setting FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION to 2.0.11961-alpha.

**Permanent fix** -  Update you "**Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs**" Nuget package to the version "**3.0.0-rc1**" or higher. Also update "**Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions**" to the version "**1.0.21**" or higher. Rebuild and test it locally and deploy to azure.

Please find the discussions on permanent fix here-  https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129

Comment: The key word here is **temporarily**. Make sure to change your app and target the latest build (~2) soon.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Platform` from `32 Bit` to `64 Bit` fixed this issue for me.
[image]