# Error building configuration in an external startup class. post Function app Upgrade 3x to 4x

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have recently upgraded a function app from 3x to 4x following all the migration related tasks required for the upgrade.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net7%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-csharp

After upgrade when trying to start the app, I could see the app running and shows the runtime version as 4.27.5.21549 but there is also an error 'AZFD0005 Error building configuration in an external startup class.'

### See full log below.

Error code
AZFD0005
Level
Error
Message
Error building configuration in an external startup class.
Details

`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExternalStartupException : Error building configuration in an external startup class. ---> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.HostInitializationException : One or more loaded extensions do not meet the minimum requirements. For more information see https://aka.ms/func-min-extension-versions. ExtensionStartupType AzureStorageWebJobsStartup from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not meet the required minimum version of 4.0.4.0. Update your NuGet package reference for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage to 4.0.4 or later. at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.ValidateExtensionRequirements(List`1 startupTypes) at /*/src/WebJobs.Script/DependencyInjection/ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 336 at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.GetExtensionsStartupTypesAsync() at /*/src/WebJobs.Script/DependencyInjection/ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 222 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.<.ctor>b__10_0() at /*/src/WebJobs.Script/DependencyInjection/ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 53 at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication,Boolean useDefaultConstructor) at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.GetStartupTypes() at /*/src/WebJobs.Script/DependencyInjection/ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 68 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.UseExternalConfigurationStartup(IWebJobsConfigurationBuilder builder,IWebJobsStartupTypeLocator startupTypeLocator,WebJobsBuilderContext context,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) at D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs : 362 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass7_3.b__8(IWebJobsStartupTypeLocator locator) at /_/src/WebJobs.Script/ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.cs : 253 End of inner exception`

Did anyone face this issue? Any help appreciated.

We have validated the runtime configuration in the settings and has all below settings appropriate.

`FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = dotnet-isolated FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = ~4 --net-framework-version = v6.0`

As per the recommendation here : https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1987
We have included 4.0.4 into the hosts.json file within the code and did a re-deployment with same error. We have done multiple restarts and refresh.

The logic app that is taking the function app's end point is giving an error BadGateway.

Please help in fixing the error in Function app

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update your **`'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=4.0.2.0'`** ***to***
**`'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.1'`**

You can directly add the below **`.csproj`** file in your Function:-

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then update the host.json and Function.cs like below:-

**`host.json:-`**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

*Default BlobTrigger code* **`Function.cs:-`**

Reference [**Ms Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python-v2,in-process,nodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp59
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

You can directly download the Nuget package from Nuget Package manager in Visual Studio like below:-

[image]

Now, Deploy this Function via **Visual Studio Publish option** into your **Function app** and ***set the Function app platform version to 64 bit from 32 bit*** like below:-

[image]

**Function Runtime Version:-**

[image]

***Function Ran successfully like below:-***

[image]

**References:-**

[Azure function failing to run with error Could not load type Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260538/azure-function-failing-to-run-with-error-could-not-load-type-microsoft-azure-web) By Joshcodes

[Azure function not running after upgrade to dotnet net6 framework even though I have the latest package - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1191955/azure-function-not-running-after-upgrade-to-dotnet)